# Reporting Software for .net application

Tags: .net, sql, reporting

I have done lots of research and have had a look at crystal report, windward reports and Telerik, but they are not what I am looking for. I need reporting software that will integrate with a .net web application that runs on several servers but doesn't require an additional application running on the machine and doesn't require any additional license fees.

It must have SQL integration, Export to word and Excel, have report parameter filtering and have charting capabilities. It would also be good if it could have dashboard view, ability for users of application to build their own reports similar to the SQL reporting model, timed report outputs the ability to send reports via email and integrate with Visual Studio 2010.

so many reporting tools out there I haven't got a clue which to use I thank you in advance

Comment: Do you want "free to develop" as well as "free to deploy"?

Comment: Could you please email me why windward was not a good fit? I'm the CTO at windward and would like to know why. david@windward.net - thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out [ActiveReports.NET from DataDynamics](http://www.datadynamics.com/Products/ActiveReports/Overview.aspx). It covers all your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The free [ReportViewer control](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/) ticks a lot of your boxes (in "local mode")

I doubt you'll get all features for free: with the ReportViewer control you can do some of the missing features yourself. For example sending emails via the .net SMTP classes and using quartz.net for scheduling.

"You get what you pay for" etc